# How to make the UIImage fit the whole UINavigationBar view's size

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, uinavigationbar

I need to set the background image for `UINavigationController`'s bars of the whole application, so I wrote the following code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "NavBar")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)

    return true
}
```

However I need to make the `UIImage` fit the bar's size, because in my case it's too big and doesn't fit the whole bar. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should automatically repeat to fill the navigation bar size but if you want it to stretch you can change set the slicing insets in Asset catalog:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/SlicinganImage.html

or in code something like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "NavBar")?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15), resizingMode: UIImageResizingMode.Stretch)

    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the size of the Image view:

```
// Set the size hard coded
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,200); 
// Or you can get the size from the view
CGRect myFrame = backGroundView.frame

// Now assign the size to the image, I normally do this is an animation
[UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
imageView.frame = myFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```